# Hotelling Multivariate Control Charts

Tags: r, string, msqc, control-charts

At my work we do a lot of [control charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart) for `n` variables for monitoring  multivariate measurement processes. I am trying to implement [Hotelling multivariate control charts](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/hotell.htm) so we can consider the correlation between variables and assess when a sample has gone out-of-control. The package [MSQC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSQC/index.html) has the function `mult.chart` to achieve this easily. The function returns some information about the data, the plot of the control chart including limits and additionally, when a sample has gone out-of-control, it decomposes it so is possible to determine which variable (or variables) are the responsible for the shift and the information is given as a list. I cannot to determine how to extract that information since the structure of the return does not follow the traditional form of name_of_data_frame$name_of_variable_of_interest, at leasts for the decomposition matrix.

```
library(MSQC)

data("carbon1")
Xmv <- mult.chart(carbon1, type = "t2") $Xmv
S <- mult.chart(carbon1, type = "t2") $covariance
colm<-nrow(carbon1)
#Phase II
data("carbon2")
Hot<-mult.chart(carbon2, type = "t2", Xmv = Xmv, S = S, colm = colm)
```

> The following(s) point(s) fall outside of the control limits[1] 4
>
> $`Decomposition of`
>   [1] 4

I tried `str(Hot)` but the part of *$`Decomposition of`* does not appear. How can I get this kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decomposition of the test statistic (T2) is not included ATM in the output of the `mult.chart`. I will include it in the next update.
One way of working around it is using:

```
library(MSQC)
data("carbon1") # dataset used in Phase I
Xmv <- mult.chart(carbon1, type = "t2") $Xmv
S <- mult.chart(carbon1, type = "t2") $covariance
colm<-nrow(carbon1)

#Phase II
data("carbon2")

co <- capture.output(Hot<-mult.chart(carbon2, type = "t2", Xmv = Xmv, S = S, colm = colm))
write(co[5:length(co)], "C:\\1\\decomp.txt") # saving it 
df <- read.table("C:\\1\\decomp.txt", sep = "", header = F)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is a very elegant solution. Thanks, As creating new tags is a privilege that I do not have yet but think that _MSQC_ should be included, could you please create it for us?

Comment: thanks. Just added the tags MSQC and control charts.